# Iptables rules, how to allow another server IPs

Tags: iptables, rules

I have 5 ips

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.5
```

i already install openvz & openvz webpanel in main ip
then create a vps with ip 1.1.1.2

i cant open 1.1.1.2, but if i disable iptables firewall, i can open it

```
service iptables save
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```

so i need to enable iptables firewall, what is the rule so i can to allow the server additional ips (1.1.1.2-1.1.1.5) in /etc/sysconfig/iptables ?

i tried these but still not right

```
-A INPUT -s 1.1.1.2 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 1.1.1.2 -d 1.1.1.5 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --s 1.1.1.2 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m iprange --src-range 1.1.1.2-1.1.1.5 -j ACCEPT
```

please help guys

this is output of iptables -L -n -v, if needed

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           source IP range 1.1.1.2-1.1.1.6
 9243 1597K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    2    92 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   
 1318 70268 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
  197 17722 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
   67  3375 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 10660 packets, 1713K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

this is output of ip a sh, if needed

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 36:40:b5:86:c5:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:40:b5:86:c5:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 1.1.1.1/29 brd 1.1.1.7 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::3640:b5ff:fe86:c56c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:40:b5:86:c5:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/void
    inet6 fe80::1/128 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: `iptables` rules can't be examined in isolation, as (like houses) they lean on one another.  Please cut-and-paste the output of `iptables -L -n -v` into your question.  I also can't quite understand what kind of traffic you're looking to allow, and from where to where - could you maybe clarify that?

Comment: its the server additional ip 1.1.1.2, I cant open it in browser address or ssh, but if disable iptables firewall, I can open it in browser address or ssh. So what is the rules to allow the server additional ip 1.1.1.2 ?

Comment: its new centos server with default iptables content

Comment: I don't know, and won't know, until you give the output asked for.

Comment: no problem,i add it in question above

Comment: Thanks.  Could you try `iptables -I INPUT 1 -m iprange --dst-range 1.1.1.2-1.1.1.5 -j ACCEPT`?  If that doesn't work, could you add the output of `ip a sh`?  I'm not entirely sure where these extra adresses are.

Comment: looks like not working. added ip a sh output in question above again, thank you for your help before

Comment: Your NIC doesn't have these addresses.  I don't see any evidence of a bridge.  The networking here seems somewhat confused.  As a last attempt on my part, you could try `iptables -F FORWARD`, and see if they're being forwarded.

Comment: hmm looks like the problem is solved, I just need flush the iptables, is this right? how can I give thanks? gbu man

Comment: The best way to thank me is to accept the summary answer I wrote, so that this question doesn't float around forever like a querulous albatross.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to formalise the investigations done in comments into an answer, so I'll do so.

The other IP addresses (which you show as 1.1.1.2 to 1.1.1.5, which incidentally [isn't following best-practice in obfuscating public IP addresses](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6063/55514)) aren't assigned to your containerisation host's NIC, but to containerised guest images, though it's not quite clear how.

This means that packets to those addresses don't count as `INPUT` traffic, as they're being routed/bridged through the host, and therefore pass through the `FORWARD` chain.

You have only one rule in your `FORWARD` chain, and it rejects everything, so the `ACCEPT` policy on the chain is no help.  When we clear the `FORWARD` rule by flushing the chain (`iptables -F FORWARD`), the `ACCEPT` policy comes into play, and traffic starts to flow.

If you would like a little more security on `FORWARD`ed traffic, you could try rules similar to the ones you post, but put them in the `FORWARD` chain, make sure you correctly differentiate between **source** and **destination** addresses, and don't forget to change the chain policy to something other than `ACCEPT` once you have them working.